# How do I assign the same id to rows having the same field

Tags: mysql

I have a **MySQL** table containing 2553 novels information (like author, year etc.), and another table containing 1059 authors (with biographical informations).

Now, authors in the second table are the writers of novels in the first table. I'd like to assign the same id to authors in the first table from second table ones.

How can I do? I already tried doing this without success.

> This is how 'novels' table should be (at the moment there isn't author_id
>   column)

```
 __ _____ ______ _________
|id|title|author|author_id|
|0 |xyz  |John  |0        |
|1 |xyz2 |John  |0        |
|2 |abc  |Rob   |1        |
|3 |qwer |Jeff  |2        |
|4 |zxcv |Jeff  |2        |
|_________________________|
```

> This is 'authors' table

```
 __ ____ _____ 
|id|name|birth|
|0 |John|1956 |
|1 |Rob |1898 |
|2 |Jeff|1932 |
|_____________|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an update join.

```
UPDATE novels INNER JOIN authors 
SET novels.author_id=authors.id where novels.author=authors.name
```

There after you should want to drop the author column in the novels table since it becomes redundant (assuming of course that all the authors are correctly represented in the authors table)

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated query :

```
UPDATE novels n
set n.author_id = (SELECT a.id FROM authors a
                   WHERE n.author = a.name)
```